# Get Redis values while scanning

Tags: postgresql, redis, key-value-store

I've created a Redis key / value index this way :

`set 7:12:321 '{"some:"JSON"}'`

The key is delimited by a colon separator, each part of the key represents a hierarchic index.
`get 7:12:321` means that I know the exact hierarchy and want only one single item

`scan 7:12:*` means that I want every item under id 7 in the first level of hierarchy and id 12 in the second layer of hierarchy.

Problem is : if I want the JSON values, I have to first `scan` (~50000 entries in a few ms) then `get` every key returned by scan one by one (800ms).

This is not very efficient. And this is the only answer I found on stackoverflow searching "scanning Redis values".

1/ Is there another way of scanning Redis to get values or key / value pairs and not only keys ? I tried `hscan` with as follows :

`hset myindex 7:12:321 '{"some:"JSON"}'
hscan myindex MATCH 7:12:*`
 
But it destroys the performance (almost 4s for the 50000 entries)

2/ Is there another data structure in Redis I could use in the same way but which could "scan for values" (`hset` ?)

3/ Should I go with another data storage solution (PostgreSQL `ltree` for instance ?) to suit my use case with huge performance ?

I must be missing something really obvious, 'cause this sounds like a common use case.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Optimization for your current solution

Instead of `get`ing every key returned by `scan` one-by-one, you should use `mget` to batch get key-value pairs, or use `pipeline` to reduce RTT.

> Efficiency problem of your current solution

`scan` command iterates all keys in the database, even if the number of keys that match the pattern is small. The performance decreases when the number of keys increases.

> Another solution

Since the hierarchic index is an integer, you can encode the hierarchic indexes into a number, and use that number as the score of a sorted set. In this way, instead of searching by pattern, you can search by score range, which is very fast with a sorted set. Take the following as an example.

Say, the first (right-most) hierarchic index is less than 1000, the second index is less than 100, then you can encode the index (e.g. `7:12:321`) into a score (321 + 12 * 1000 + 7 * 100 * 1000 = 712321). Then set the score and the value into a sorted set: `zadd myindex 712321 '{"some:"JSON"}'`.

When you want to search keys that match `7:12:*`, just use `zrangebyscore` command to get data with a score between 712000 and 712999: `zrangebyscore myindex 712000 712999 withscores`.

In this way, you can get key (decoded with the returned score) and value together. Also it should be faster than the `scan` solution.

**UPDATE**

The solution has a little problem: members of sorted set must be unique, so you cannot have 2 keys with the same value (i.e. json string).

```
// insert OK
zadd myindex 712321 '{"the_same":"JSON"}'
// failed to insert, members should be unique
zadd myindex 712322 '{"the_same":"JSON"}'
```

In order to solve this problem, you can combine the key with the json string to make it unique:

```
zadd myindex 712321 '7:12:321-{"the_same":"JSON"}'
zadd myindex 712321 '7:12:322-{"the_same":"JSON"}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The solution of the score is very clever. I'll certainly have to adapt it since the hierarchic keys are not really organized as "purely" as I mentionned in my question (I over-simplified). But there's definitely something worth experimenting around this idea. In the meantime, I had found about `mget` in the docs I can see improvements, but yeah, less clever than your solution, for sure ;) Thanks !

Comment: @Javier92 I found there's a little problem with the original solution. Please see my update for the solution.

Comment: Don't worry, first part + last part of the key makes an unique identifier. The parts in between are only used for indexing purpose. So it's easy to create some unique json field.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a Sorted Set and lexicographical ranges as long as you only need to perform prefix searches. For more information about this and indexing in general refer to http://redis.io/topics/indexes

Updated with an example:

Consider the following -

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD anotherindex 0 '7:12:321:{"some:"JSON"}'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX anotherindex [7:12: [7:12:\xff
1) "7:12:321:{\"some:\"JSON\"}"
```

Now go and read about this so you 1) understand what it does and 2) know how to avoid possible pitfalls :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not sure I understand correctly. In the docs your mentionned, `ZADD` always has `0` as key. Thus my hierarchy which was the key becomes the value ? Where will my JSON being stored. Sorry if this is trivial for you. Could you give an example of what you have in mind with `ZADD` and `ZRANGEBYLEX` ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example, even though I'm realizing just now ! Much appreciated. i'll definitely use it for prefixed searches